# Stop requesting url with cURL when using ranges

Tags: http, curl, request

For example, if I am requesting this url:

```
curl http://www.example.com/index.html?page=[1-100]
```

Imagine that only the range [1-3] exists in the query page. Why can't the cURL stop requesting urls when it arrives to number 4?

What I want is cURL to stop when it starts to request the page number 5 (since page 4 would return 404 code)

Comment: because cURL is just sending request. How could cURL knows that your URL works only on 1,2 and 3?

Comment: Because the server returns a status code (404 in this case). In fact with the option -f it doesn't create a file if the server return an error status code (and you are outputing the urls)

Comment: yes, but you ask cURL to do a range fron 1 to 100. Maybe 4 will be a 404 but 5 will work. so cURL will try every value in your range

Comment: Yes, it sounds coherent. But in case of pages for example, it is evident that if number 4 does not exists then number 5 will neither exists.

Comment: not at all ! It could be evident if you talk about pagination. But what if it's ID from user ? and let's say you have user from 1 to 100 but you delete user 5 ?

Comment: That's true. I was only trying to avoid a loop because in my case it is as I described above. But it seems not possible...

Comment: i don't think it's possible to cURL to do it alone.
But you can write a script to do it, like  @ministry did

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) function with the `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE` option. The `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE` returns the HTTP Code for the last requested page.

EDIT: Here is an example below which will also return the content of the page (assuming you want that functionality, if not you can modify it).

This while loop begins at `page=0` and will continue to increment to `page=1, page=2, etc...` until it reaches a non-existent page and then will break out of the loop.

```
$response_code = 0;
$i = 0;

while ($response_code != 404 && $i <= 100)
{   
         $cURL_handler = curl_init();

         curl_setopt($cURL_handler, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/index.html?page=' . $i);

         curl_setopt($cURL_handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

         $page_content = curl_exec($cURL_handler);

         $response_code = curl_getinfo($cURL_handler, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  

         curl_close($cURL_handler);
    $i++; 
}
```